# How can I request elevated permissions in a bash script's begin and let it go at the end?

Tags: bash, elevated-privileges

I have a script (*myscript.sh*) which runs a few commands which need *elevated privileges* (i.e. needs to run with `sudo`).

Script is quite complex, but to demonstrate it is like below:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "hello"
command1_which_needs_sudo
echo "hello2"
command2_which_needs_sudo
echo "hello3"
...
```

If I run it as a normal user without the required privileges:

```
$ ./myscript.sh
hello
must be super-user to perform this action
```

However if I run it with the correct privileges, it will work fine:

```
$ sudo ./myscript.sh
hello
hello2
hello3
```

Can I somehow achieve to run `myscript.sh` without `sudo`, and make the script requesting the elevated privileges **only once** in the beginning (and pass it back once it has finished)?

So obviously, `sudo command1_which_needs_sudo` will not be good, as command2 also need privileges.

How can I do this if I don't want to create another file, and due to script complexity I also don't want to do this with heredoc syntax?

Comment: What _exactly_ do you mean re: "don't want to do this with heredoc syntax"?

Comment: If you're okay with a subprocess, but just don't want to use a heredoc, that's fine, we can work with that. If you're not okay with your escalated bits happening in a subprocess, that's not workable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your main concern is code clarity, using wrapper functions can do a lot of good.

```
# call any named bash function under sudo with arbitrary arguments
run_escalated_function() {
  local function_name args_q
  function_name=$1; shift || return
  printf -v args_q '%q ' "$@"
  sudo bash -c "$(declare -f "$function_name"); $function_name $args_q"
}

privileged_bits() {
  command1_which_needs_sudo
  echo "hello2"
  command2_which_needs_sudo
}

echo "hello"
run_escalated_function privileged_bits
echo "hello3"
```

Comment: Pretty good, but as @Fravadona highlighted, this one also doesn't revoke the privilegization after escalated function finished. I.e. this restores the `$EUID`, but I can run other commands which requires elevated privileges without entering the password again. To conclude this, I dropped `sudo -k` after your `sudo bash ...` line which seems to do the job.

Comment: To be fair: this is the normal behavior of `sudo`, it has a timeout to revoke the privileges anyway.

Comment: We're using the word "privileges" to mean different things. In traditional UNIX terminology, being uid 0 (or having `CAP_SYS_ADMIN`) is what constitutes being privileged; sudo being inside its timeout to not prompt for credentials again is a separate thing.

Comment: So, calling sudo doesnt make me privileged in that timeframe?

Comment: It makes _the command sudo started_ privileged, but not other commands. Child process of sudo (when using the default destination of root) are privileged, but not its younger siblings.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run the script with root privileges without having to type `sudo` in the terminal nor having to type the password more than once then you can use:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$EUID" -ne 0 ]
then
    exec sudo -s "$0" "$@"
fi

echo "hello"
command1_which_needs_sudo
echo "hello2"
command2_which_needs_sudo
echo "hello3"
# ...

sudo -k
```

---

###### Update:

If your goal is to execute one part of the script with `sudo` rights then using a **quoted here‑document** is probably the easiest solution; there won't be any syntax issues because the current shell won't expand anything in it.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

echo "hello"

sudo -s var="hello2" <<'END_OF_SUDO'

command1_which_needs_sudo
echo "$var"
command2_which_needs_sudo

END_OF_SUDO
sudo -k

echo "hello3"
#...
```

**remark:** take notice that you can use external values in the here-document script by setting `varname=value` in the `sudo` command.

Comment: This doesn't drop permissions when they're no longer needed, though; the OP is asking how to escalate _only part_ of their script.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy You're right; after completion of the script the terminal keeps the `sudo` rights; is it even possible to revoke them without `sudo -k` or natural timeout? I tested your solution and I got the same problem (tested on macOS)

Comment: I didn't take the OP to mean "privileges" meaning the cached permissions; I took them to mean they wanted the script to no longer run as UID 0 past the part that needs it. If you look at my answer, the `echo "hello3"` is run under the original UID, not as root. (If you found otherwise, could you explain exactly how you tested? If you change `echo "test3"` to, say, `echo "test: $(id -u)"`, that should serve the purpose).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Sorry I didn't understand correctly OP needs and your first comment. I updated my answer with the quoted here-document solution because OP might not know about it (IMHO there's no syntax problems with it)

Comment: Yes, this is quite good and easy!